# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am getting the error when I run this code in google Colab

```
folders = glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/train/*')
```

[![enter image description here]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You tried to use glob method directly, take the following code sample which was tested in Google colab environment. It should help to fix your issue.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')


import glob
path = glob.glob("/gdrive/MyDrive/*")
for file_or_folder in path:
    print(file_or_folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, the path should be defined differently.

For that, initially import glob and drive module as mentioned below

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
import glob
```

And then using this, you can easily access the file as follows

```
folders = glob.glob('/gdrive/MyDrive/Datasets/Tomato/train/*')
```

Here if you see the difference in the copied path and the defined path is

```
'/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/Tomato/test' is what coppid form the drive

'/gdrive/MyDrive/Datasets/Tomato/train/*' is how you need to define the path
```